# Changing the name of a textfile

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code:

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\fatura.txt"))
    {            
        string numcont = _transaction.PartyFederalTaxID;
        double numenc = _transaction.BillToPartyID;
        double numfatura = _transaction.TransDocNumber;
        DateTime data = _transaction.CreateDate;
        double valor = _transaction.TotalAmount;
        short zona = transaction.BillToPartyAddressID;
        double precoantesdisc = bsoItemTrans.BSOItemTransactionDetail.TransactionDetail.PackUnitPrice;
        double preconet = transaction.TotalTransactionAmount;
        double quantidade = transaction.Details.Count;
        double bonus = _transaction.TotalPaymentDiscountAmount;
        string valorStr = valor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string preconetStr = preconet.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string precoantesdiscStr = precoantesdisc.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);           

            writer.WriteLine($"{numcont};{numenc};{numfatura};{data:dd/MM/yyyy};{valorStr};{zona};");
            foreach (ItemTransactionDetail detail in transaction.Details)
            {
                var item = MyApp.DSOCache.ItemProvider.GetItem(detail.ItemID, MyApp.SystemSettings.BaseCurrency);                    
                double taxRate = MyApp.DSOCache.TaxesProvider.GetTaxRateFromTaxableGroupID(detail.TaxableGroupID, "PRT","CON");
                string barcode = item.BarCode;
                writer.WriteLine($"{barcode};{taxRate};{precoantesdiscStr};{preconetStr};{quantidade};{bonus}");
            }

        }
        MessageBox.Show("gravou");
    }
```

I need to change the name of the text file to the bill number(In this case is the variable "numfactura").
Is that possible?

And I need to create a new file for each bill.

Is that possible?

Comment: create a string to store the filename in and build that filename up however you want. e.g. `string fileName = numfatura.ToString() + ".txt";` Obviously you will have to do this before `new StreamWriter()`

Comment: But if i do it before the StreamWriter it wont read the variable "numfatura"

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `System.IO.File.Move()` method, `Move()` the file to a new name.

```
System.IO.File.Move("OldFileName", "NewFileName");
```

Comment: Where should I use this? Just to be sure I'm using it correctly.

Comment: After your file is written, which means `using(...){ ... } <here>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
double numfatura = _transaction.TransDocNumber;
string fileName = numfatura + ".txt";
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
```

I don't know how you enumerate your bills but put your writing code in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: This saves the file as "fileName"

Comment: It shouldn't. It will save it with whatever name is in the fileName variable. Have you entered `new StreamWriter("fileName"))` ? There hsould be no quotes `"` in the new StreamWriter if you are passing it a variable. Notice my answer has no quotes.

Comment: I literally ctrl+c and ctrl+v.